# Python Django Inlines Control Order

Tags: django

I am trying to accomplish the very simple task of **having a inline not appearing at the end of the admin panel**. I have no problem making an inline appear at the end, but that's not what I want. I am looking for a way to control the ordering of the inline within the other attributes of the class?

So far I've googled it with no luck. Any ideas?

```
class MyInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    ...

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [MyInlineAdmin]

    fieldsets = [
        ("Some Label", {
                "fields": ["field1", "field2"]
            }),
        ("Other Label", {
            "fields": ["field3", "field4"]
        })
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class MyInlineAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Child_model
  ordering = [’child1’, ’child2’]

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  model = Parent_Model
  inlines = [MyInlineAdmin]


  fieldsets = [
    ("Some Label", {
            "fields": ["field1", "field2"]
        }),
    ("Other Label", {
        "fields": ["field3", "field4"]
    })
   ]

  admin.site.register(Parent_Model,MyModelAdmin)
```